# How to map one dataframe to another dataframe for cross-sectional panel data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have df1 and df2, where df1 is a balanced panel of 20 stocks with daily datetime data. Due to missing days (weekends, holidays) I am assigning each day available to an integer of how many days I have (1-252). df2 is a 2 column matrix which maps each day to the integer.

```
df2

    date integer
2020-06-26, 1
2020-06-29, 2
2020-06-30, 3
2020-07-01, 4
2020-07-02, 5
...
2021-06-25, 252
```

I would like to map these dates to every asset I have in df1 for each date, therefore returning a single column of (0-252) repeated for each asset.

So far I have tried this:

```
df3 = (df1.merge(df2, left_on='date', right_on='integer'))
```

which returns an empty dataframe - I dont think I'm fully understanding the logic here

Comment: Merge on right index instead? Why are you merging on date and integer?

Comment: @dm2 I tried that with the following code: df3 = (df1.merge(df2,left_on='date',right_index=True)), yet I am still left with an empty df3

Comment: Maybe try to `set_index("date") ` on both df and then use `left_index=True` and `right_index=True` in `pd.merge`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both `df1` and `df2` having the same column label as `date` hence,

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2)
```